# phabricator cannot find dockerized mysql in dockerized php container

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, phabricator

I am trying to launch phabricator as a docker image. The problem is that phabricator returns a `Cannot Find MySQL!` page when I visit phabricator/webroot. When I try and specify the `mysql.host`, `mysql.port`, `mysql.user`, and `mysql.pass` parameters, it still seems to fail.

> EDIT: I am trying this on macOS "Sierra" with docker-machine.

I'm doing this by separating out three components:

1. nginx image
2. php-fpm image
3. mysql image

The nginx image and php-fpm image share data via the same volume. Specifically, I'm storing the requisite phabricator files (phabricator, liphutil, arcanist), inside a data/ dir. The structure of my docker project looks like this:

```
docker-project/
    - docker-compose.yml
    - php_setup.conf
    + data/
        + phabricator/
        + arcanist/
        + liphutil/
    + nginx/
        - Dockerfile
    + php-fpm/
        - Dockerfile
```

The `php_setup.conf` is just the requisite nginx configuration for the phabricator php project, which is copied into the nginx container.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "2"
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: nginx/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/srv
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: php-fpm/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./data:/srv
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - MYSQL_USER=phabricator
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=12345
```

I am able to `telnet mysql 3306` host from the php-fpm image, so it is clearly available. However, I'm not sure if this issue is arising because I have the phabricator projects on a host volume, rather than in the container themselves.

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Log error provided by phabricator upon request:

> Unable to establish a connection to any database host (while trying "phabricator_config"). All masters and replicas are completely unreachable.

**data/phabricator/conf/local/local.json**

```
{
  "mysql.port": "3306",
  "mysql.pass": "12345",
  "mysql.user": "phabricator",
  "mysql.host": "mysql"
}
```

Comment: what's the start sequence of these containers? can you try `depends_on: mysql` for your php service?

Comment: Paste your phabricator_config

Comment: @TarunLalwani I'm assuming you're referring to the `local.json` file provided for configuration (I added it above). The "phabricator_config" is a variable passed into `addPhabricatorConfig(...)` in the phabricator code. It results in a reference to `mysql.host`, etc...

Comment: @Metaphox I forgot to mention I've tried making the startup sequence explicit. unfortunately, depends_on doesn't seem to work. :(

Comment: May be the config is not getting loaded at all? Also try to connect using  mysql client cli using the credentials your provided to make sure DB is connecting fine

Comment: @TarunLalwani That was a great suggestion. While I could connect to the mysql server, it turns out the permission were restrictive for the user `phabricator`. After giving `phabricator` global permissions, the phabricator app was able to connect. What a misleading error message though :/

Comment: Glad you could solve it. Thats what debugging is for, don't believe the error messages

Answer (score 1):

Despite the error message saying that phabricator cannot connect/find MySQL, it turns out that the permissions granted to the `phabricator` user were too restrictive.

Solution: Grant global permission to the phabricator user.